# check if two regexes match the same strings in java

Tags: java, regex, state-machine, dfa

I have two regular expressions (simple example: "[0-9]+" and "[0123456789]+"). I'd like to see if they match exactly the same inputs. Is there a built-in function for doing this check in java? If not, is there a relatively easy algorithm for doing the check? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way of doing this in Java. As far as algorithm goes, the "simplest" (in terms of explanation) would be to construct the DFAs for each regex, run a DFA minimization algorithm on both, and compare the results.

Comment: That is actually a very nontrivial problem, especially since Java regular expressions aren't "regular" in the strictest sense. I don't think you'll find any easy way of doing that.

Comment: Do you want to check modern-day regexes (supporting look-arounds, back-references an the likes)? Or are they "real" regular expressions (like the simple example you posted)? If it's the first, I don't think there's a relatively easy solution (if a solution at all!).

Comment: I don't think there is a way to generically prove two regular expressions are identical even mathematically. You can't even prove the expressions will halt. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Although, if you really want an answer, you can just guess and check :) Just throw a ton of random strings at them; the more you throw, the more likely two expressions are equal.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis, that will take too much time for regexes that could possibly match many characters. And a regex like `^(?![\s\S]).$` would never match anything at all, making it hard to check.

Comment: @BartKiers: I was half joking anyhow. However, if you *really* needed to know for some reason, you could always farm it out to AWS or something. I suspect that that would be overkill for the asker, but you never know.

Comment: If the equivalence problem for the class of regexen the OP is asking about is decidable, then you can come up with the notion of a canonical form for a given regex.  Then take two regexen and see if their canonical forms are the same.  It would be theoretically doable but could be slow.  If you add backreferences, etc. then you are beyond type-3 languages, and equivalence is not decidable.

Comment: I only want to check "real" regular expressions. The guess and check method is not practical. I've never used AWS, so I'm not sure what Tikhon is suggesting. I'm not sure how to get the canonical form of a regex. I wouldn't be using backreferences. Amber's response seems to make the most sense, although it's less than I hoped to find.

Answer (score 6):

There actually is an algorithmic way to check for regex equality, although it's complicated. Here's how:

1. Convert both regexes into their equivalent NFA. This is a [well-known and defined process.](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/360Book/RegLang/RtoN/)
2. Convert both NFAs to DFAs via the [powerset construction.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)
3. Given that intersection and complementation are [closed and well defined](http://tagh.de/tom/wp-content/uploads/fsm_unweigtedautomata.pdf) for DFAs, construct the XOR of the two DFAs. (This is somewhat an abuse of notation, but if the automota are A and B, construct AB'+A'B)
4. This resultant machine represents the difference between the original regexes (any string in one but not the other). Now just run [graph reachability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) from the start to end of the DFA. If it fails, they're equal, on success, not equal!

Answer (score 0):

First, it is exactly the same. Second, I cannot imagine built-in function that does what you want. Think: you actually want to match the regex against several inputs. What inputs? Random strings? In this case the chance that your random string contains digits only is very law.

I can a little bit change your question. Here is my version.

*I have 2 regular expressions and want to verify that they function equally. *

This question makes sense. In this case I can write a series of unit test using one of popular unit test frameworks (e.g. JUnit or TestNG) and run the same tests against these 2 regexes. I am expecting the same results every time. But I have to write the strings myself. For example

- empty string
- string with letters only
- string with numbers only
- string with special characters
- string with unicode characters
- mixture of previous

*etc, etc*

Comment: Heh, that is what I was sort of going for in my last comment (about using random strings). Except, instead of a unit-testing framework, you should probably use something like QuickCheck. You should be using QuickCheck anyhow, but I digress.

Comment: I would prefer a way to check equivalency of regex expressions without testing them on inputs. This is simply because there are too many possible inputs--in fact, a practically infinite number of possible inputs.

Comment: Regex expressions are not like mathematical formulas: you can't derived them and prove their equivalence. They are algorithms and, as such, are very unlikely to compile in the same way unless it's something absolutely trivial like `[[:digit:]] === \d`.